# Why 'part' is mounted inside LVM

Tags: lvm, centos7, domu

In lsblk command. I am seeing a 'part' type sub partition mounted under 'lvm' as below.

```
[root@srv ~]# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8:0 0 447.1G 0 disk
└─sda4 8:4 0 379.2G 0 part
  └─md3 9:3 0 379.1G 0 raid1
    ├─volgroup1-vsv1002--051j--vnifpdojudkszbiw 253:0 0 20G 0 lvm
    └─volgroup1-vsv1003--0foy--e7wcu4kzg0fgbyeb 253:1 0 50G 0 lvm
      └─volgroup1-vsv1003--0foy--e7wcu4kzg0fgbyeb1 253:2 0 49.9G 0 part <==
```

The lvm 'volgroup1-vsv1003' is a windows domU. As per my observation the 'part' disappears after main node reboot.

Can some please advice what is 'part' and why this is getting created ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an MS-DOS partition table in the domU VM. Which is normal for Windows. The alternative disklabel you could have for windows is GPT.
Because the virtual disk is a LVM logical volume, you will see this "virtual" partition inside the logical volume.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any clue why / how 'part' disappear on main node reboot

Comment: I think that udev did ignore the partition table on that volume, as you usually do not use a partition table on a LVM logical volume. Only VMs, containers and storage servers (e.g. iSCSI) are using this kind of setup.